# how to prove $g(z)$ is entire?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

let $f$ be a function such that $f$  is continuous on $\overline {\Bbb D}$ and analytic and **real valued** on on $\Bbb D$

($\Bbb D $ is the open unit disc centered at 0 )

define

$$g(z) =\begin{cases}
f(z),  & \text{if |z| $\le$ 1} \\
\overline {f(1/\overline {z})}, & \text{if |z| $\gt$ 1}
\end{cases}$$

is $g$ entire?, how to prove, hints?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take $f(z)=z$. Then $g$ is not even continuous at $i$, because $g(i)=i$, but if $\lambda\in(1,+\infty)$, then$$g(\lambda i)=\overline{1/\overline{\lambda i}}=-\frac i\lambda.$$